# HttpContext.Current.Cache - When does this gets cleared automatically?

Tags: .net, iis, caching

In my Web forms application I am using HttpContext.Current.Cache to store some information which different forms use to avoid going to db every time.

My Question is, when will this get cleared? Or it will remain there until I remove it through code or restart IIS ?

Comment: Are you talking about the whole cache or certain items?

Comment: google is your friend... see this, and many more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx

Comment: @Oded, talking about, all cache items

Comment: @sJhonny, Thanks for reply Johnny. That page says "Caching is implemented by the Cache class, with cache instances private to each application. The cache lifetime is tied to that of the application; when the application is restarted, the Cache object is recreated."

So this means, Unless we restart Application from IIS Manager cache will remain in memory?? Provided we did not use any expiration parameter to add cache items and server is not running out of memory.

Comment: possibly. although I wouldn't recommend not using expiry parameter

Answer (score 13):

The cache is held in memory until the process is stopped.

So, resetting IIS or recycling the application pool would also clear the cache.

Comment: What should I do to ensure that My Cache items always remain in cache? I can put them in cache on Application_Start in Global.asax .. Is it fine ? Or I need to do something else aswell?

Comment: @dFriend - The cached items will remain in cache, wherever you add them. They will only expire on reset/recycle (or if instructed to).

Comment: Doesn't IIS receycle automatically when for instance there is not enough memory available anymore?

Comment: In localhost enviroment, is it cache deleted after build of solution. It seems it is. I have two queries hich take about 40s to complete but every time I build the solution I have to wait 40-50s. Is it a way to save in cache so after rebuild I don't have to wait database queries to populate the cache.

Comment: Yes, a rebuild will also clear the cache, as the app-pool needs to reload everything. One way around it is to use an out of process cache - like Redis @impeRAtoR.

Comment: I just spent two hours trying  to figure out redis. Is is complicated to get started or find examples in C# usage. Is it possible to use mongoDB for cache. I get started with mongo few months ago in two minutes.

Comment: @impeRAtoR - I gave redis as an example. Any out of process storage would work (databases, mongoDB, redis etc...)

Answer (score 10):

According to MSDN, the cache will be cleared on the following scenarios:

1. The code manually clears an entry.

   - By using the `Remove` method of the `Cache` object.
2. The cache entry expires.

   - By using the `absoluteExpiration` or `slidingExpiration` parameters of the `Add` and `Insert` methods of the `Cache` object.
3. A dependency of the cached item is removed from the cache.

   - By defining a dependency through the use of the `CacheDependency` class when adding items to the cache.
   - Removing a dependency will remove/expire all dependent items.
4. The host process ends (application or IIS reset, application pool recycle, etc).
5. System memory becomes scarce (automatic - called **scavenging** - see below).

### Scavenging

Even though cases 1 to 4 are mostly self-explanatory, the system memory availability scenario might not be evident at first. See the quote below from the MSDN article on caching application data.

> The Cache class offers powerful features that allow you to customize how items are cached and how long they are cached. For example, **when system memory becomes scarce, the cache automatically removes seldom-used or low-priority items to free memory**. This technique is referred to as **scavenging**, and is one of the ways that the cache ensures that out-of-date data does not consume valuable server resources.

According to the same article, you can set priority levels on your cached items to try to secure your most important items from being automatically removed by using the `CacheItemPriority` enumeration.

```
var expiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddHours(24);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
    "myKey",
    myValue,
    null,
    expiresAt,
    Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
    CacheItemPriority.High,
    null
);
```

Note that you also have the option of setting the priority to `NotRemovable`, which would disable the automatic removal of this item through scavenging. However, please note that this is not the default behavior.

Also note that, if you use large amounts of memory through cache by setting the priority to `NotRemovable`, your application might throw run time memory availability errors.

Information on how much of your system's memory is available for your application's cache can be retrieved through the property `EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit` of the `Cache` object.

### Logging/Debugging

If you wish to carefully understand the status of the cache on your application through logs (for instance), it's usually useful to look at the moments where the item is inserted and removed from the cache.

Logging the moment where the item is inserted is usually pretty simple, since you only have to look for calls to the `Add` or `Insert` methods of the `Cache` object.

However, since cached items may be automatically removed, to log the removal of an item, you should use the `CacheItemRemovedCallback` delegate type when inserting items to the cache.

This can be really useful when debugging/improving legacy applications that rely heavily on caching data.

See MSDN article below for more details.

#### Sources:

**MSDN Articles:**

- [Caching Application Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [How to: Notify an Application When an Item Is Removed from the Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kxdx246.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

**API:**

- [Cache.Remove Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.remove.aspx)
- [Cache.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx)
- [Cache.Insert Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77.aspx)
- [CacheDependency Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [CacheItemPriority Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitempriority.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Cache.EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.effectivepercentagephysicalmemorylimit(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

I know this question is back from 2011. However, it took me some time to figure out a bug in a legacy application I was working on that was caused by the automatic clear up policy based on available physical memory.

Hopefully, this answer will help someone else.

And thanks to @J. Ed and @Oded for their answer and comments. They helped me get in the right track to find the issue.