# Does IIS reset clear local data cache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, asp.net-mvc-4

Can I be sure that an IIS reset or application pool recycle will clear local asp.net data cache?

Essentially something similar to this (the end result, that is):

```
public void ClearApplicationCache()
{
    List<string> keys = new List<string>();

    // retrieve application Cache enumerator
    IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();

    // copy all keys that currently exist in Cache
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        keys.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString());
    }

    // delete every key from cache
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
    {
        Cache.Remove(keys[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it will , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159523/httpcontext-current-cache-when-does-this-gets-cleared-automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed clears all cache as per Imran's response.

Answer (score 0):

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Caching.Cache.GetEnumerator()'

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to IIS express

> `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\" run this appcmd.exe list site`
>   `/xml | appcmd delete site /in`

This will delete all the sites, enjoy!

You can spawn this as a task from your app..