# I am not able to store data in server side cache for one day

Tags: caching

I have around 10 lines of converted text. I  want to store that text  to a cache for a day. I am using Microsoft translator to convert the text so I don't want to  call the Microsoft service for the same text again and again.

my code:

```
string key = "cachekey"

textConverted =  "i am using ";

HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, textConverted, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Comment: And what is your problem exactly?

Comment: the data is not saving to cache for one day.  it is saving for max 10 mins.

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159523/httpcontext-current-cache-when-does-this-gets-cleared-automatically), the cache is reset if you restart IIS. This also happens when you restart your project in Visual Studio. Could that be the problem?